# Help Reducing simple fraction

Tags: fractions

This has got to be easy, but for some reason I just don't see it, probably because it's late.

Solution key to a quiz we took online says that:

$\frac{A^2 + A + AB}{(A + B)(A + B + 1)}$

can get reduced down to

$\frac{A}{A+B}$

but I can't seem to get it there.  Any help?

Comment: Oh my god, I knew it was late.  Disregard

Comment: $$A^2+A+AB=A(A+1+B)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use $A^2+A+AB=A(A+1+B)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is because $A^2+A+AB=A(A+B+1)$.